# Puppeteer. How click on btn after API load data in input

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Have SPA. Open form with cople imputs(value inside imputs generate js).
When i enter some code in one of my special field for search - after that all of my fields take some data from API.
After all the inputs accept their own data - i click the button to create the entry.
Can i push button after complited load data in inputs from API?

im try stuff like that, but its dosen't work - button dont wait and click

```
    await page2.focus("body > div.viewport > div.overlay.dialog-overlay > div > div.tabs-container > div.tabs-wrapper > ul > li.tab-content.active > div > div.content > div:nth-child(1) > div.content > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.content > input");

    await page2.keyboard.type('14129513');  //after type - make req/res for load other fields
    

    page2.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle0'})  //dont work


    const daliButton = await page2.waitForSelector('body > div.viewport > div.overlay.dialog-overlay > div > div.tabs-container > div.tabs-wrapper > ul > li.tab-content.active > div > div.buttons > div.button.waves-effect.action')
    await daliButton.evaluate(b => b.click());
```

my solition right now is timeout

```
await page2.focus("body > div.viewport > div.overlay.dialog-overlay > div > div.tabs-container > div.tabs-wrapper > ul > li.tab-content.active > div > div.content > div:nth-child(1) > div.content > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.content > input");
    await page2.keyboard.type('14129513');
    

    function delay(time) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve) { 
          setTimeout(resolve, time)
      });
    }


    await delay(2000);


    const daliButton = await page2.waitForSelector('body > div.viewport > div.overlay.dialog-overlay > div > div.tabs-container > div.tabs-wrapper > ul > li.tab-content.active > div > div.buttons > div.button.waves-effect.action')
    await daliButton.evaluate(b => b.click());
```

I also tried to take the values of the fields whether they were empty or with data, but the values were taken too quickly - when the information via the API had not yet arrived and had not been filled in the fields

Does anyone know what the code should be so that the button is clicked only when the data in all fields is filled?
Without using timeout of course)

Comment: You're missing an `await` in front of your `waitForNavigation` call, although I'd use `Promise.all` to make sure there's no race condition between the API response settling and the event that triggers it. Timeouts are usually poor solutions, as you seem to be aware.

Comment: @ggorlen Ty for ur answer) I'm tried...dosen't work.  Some guys have simular situation, like i understand, for SPA - no alternative for timeout right now https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1412

Comment: That link shows the pattern I suggested, with `Promise.all`. If you added that or fixed your missing `await`, can you please [edit] the post to show your new code? If things still don't work even after `Promise.all`, please explain why and share a URL so others can run the code to reproduce the problem. Thanks. As an aside, I [don't recommend using those hyper-rigid browser-generated selectors](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#misusing-developer-tools-generated-selectors).

Comment: @ggorlen ty man again, mb truely for SPA or for my case getting data without reloading and without changing the URL, but all the manipulation with `page2.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle0'})` didn't work for me. What worked for me was `wait for page2.waitForResponse(response => response.status() === 200)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's what working

```
await page2.waitForResponse(response => response.status() === 200)
```

EDIT: oh...that's working just for 6/10 cases lol.

I think function `waitForResponse` working kind of delay and on this time all scripts and fields load and mostly ready for next step - to click button and create record

EDIT prt2: after API load data in inputs - i see what that inputs take a new class, so if u have simular case u can use next code:

```
 await page.waitForFunction('document.querySelector("ur selector").classList.contains("active")')//waits until a new class "active" is added to the selector
```